# Checking ssh and vnc connections using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

Hello im trying to check devices if they are accessible or not with the ssh and vnc. I need to use bash scripting. Can anyone help? Thanks...

I tried to do with </dev/udp/ but it says accessible for every port and ip. What can i do anything else or am i trying something in the wrong seas.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use TCP instead of UDP:

- SSH: `: </dev/tcp/HOSTNAME/22`
- VNC: `: </dev/tcp/HOSTNAME/5900`

Use these commands in an `if`:

```
TARGET=...
if : 2>/dev/null </dev/tcp/"$TARGET"/22; then
  echo SSH connect to host "$TARGET" OK.
else
  echo SSH connect to host "$TARGET" failed.
fi
```